# How to fix 'Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream' error when running karate on SSL url

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, karate

I am using Karate for web services testing and I am running into an issue when making requests to SSL url. I get the following error:

**ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream**

I generate the request data by calling another class and pass this data to the request as shown in the code snippet below.

In the karate-config.js I have added the *karate.configure('ssl', true)* and all other variants of the string value to no avail.

I am running karate version 0.9.0 on jdk jdk1.8.0_171 using maven 3.5.3

```
* def data = Java.type('mdmtests.PersonData').insert('<abs:PersonDetails>', core, queryFields)

* configure headers = { Content-Type: 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',  Keep-Alive: 'timeout=10, max=1000'}
Given request data
When soap action '"document/http://siebel.com/CustomUI:..."'
Then status 200
* xml soapResponseXml = response
Then match soapResponseXml /Envelope/Body/ListOfPerson/PersonDetails/IdentificationNo == person.SOC_SECURITY_NUM
```

When I run the same scenario to another server without SSL enabled, the request is sent successfully and I don't get an error. Additionally, I can send requests to the SSL enabled url using SOAP UI without any problems. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as you forgot to switch the URL to `https://`, do check.

Else it is very hard for me to tell without any more data. If you can't find what you are missing, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: looks like this is an issue with the set up of strong crypto, after we got more details - refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/672#issuecomment-461364938

You'll have to figure this out on your own unless you can give us a way to replicate this - ensure permissions of the new files are ok, the SSL compatibility between client and server is fine etc.

Comment: The URL is correctly pointing to https://

I have created an issue in github for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After leaving this for months, the solution stemmed from several changes I needed to make to Java and the karate project. To clarify, I was using a self-signed certificate on the server.

1. Imported the self-signed certificate to my keystore using keytool
2. Added the [Java Cryptography Extension](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) with unlimited strength to JAVA_HOME; [installation steps](https://dzone.com/articles/install-java-cryptography-extension-jce-unlimited)
3. In the karate-config.js file, I added the following:

   `karate.configure('ssl', { trustAll: true, algorithm: "TLSv1.2" });`
4. In the pom.xml I changed the Http client dependency from karate-apache to karate-jersey

It was through a lot of trial and error that I finally got it to work, I realise that some of the steps might not be relevant for all but Step 4 definitely stopped the unexpected EOF issue.